# Is a logician a “logicus” or a “logicista”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, word-choice, science

I am wondering how to translate the noun “logician” into Latin.

Smith & Hall suggests “dialecticus” but I had in mind the modern discipline as a formal science, not the argumentation exercise of Antiquity. So using the root “logic” is probably a better idea.

From there, there are two possibilities,

- “logicista” (from Entick's Latin-English dictionary),
- “logicus” (used several times in the Latin version of Wikipedia).

Which one is of better Latinity? Please also feel free to suggest another root if at any point in my research I have missed something.

Comment: Your title said *logista* but the text said *logicista*. I took the liberty to conform the title to the text. Feel free to edit if I got it the wrong way around!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with ***logicus***.

First, I fully agree with you that starting from *logic-* is the best option by far.
Language is used for the purpose of communication, and using a word that looks similar to those used in other languages certainly helps communicate what the profession is.

Second, there is good precedent in classical Latin to use words like *logicus* for similar professions.
For example, Cicero mentions in *De oratore* (1.44) at least *mathematici*, *grammatici*, and *musici*.

That the word *logicus* does not seem to appear in classical literature is not sufficient grounds to dismiss it.
It is a very natural latinization of the Greek adjective *λογικός* and it is indeed used in later eras.
Ancient Romans had no term for the profession, but if they needed one, *logicus* would have been a likely choice.

The suffix *-ista* appears to be rare to the extent that a corpus search gives zero hits for relevant words containing *-cista-*.
I would dismiss *logicista* or *logista* as worse style.